# Can i find such a polynomial?

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Is there a practical interpretation of the following?
I would like a function $f$ s.t: for a set of distinct values $S=\{s_i\}_{i=0}^n$:
$$f(s_i,s_j)=1,  \forall j \in S,i\neq j$$ and 
$f(s_i,s_j) \neq 1, i\neq j $

Example:
$S={1,2,3}$ then i want such $f$ such that:

$f(1,2)=1$

$f(1,3)=1$

$f(2,1)=1$

$f(2,3)=1$

$f(3,1)=1$

$f(3,2)=1$

Put it in clear. Fixing the first input of $f$ from a value of the set then all the other possible values given as input to the $f$ should evaluate to 1. What i can find such $f$? Can i just say that it exists?

Answer (score 2):

The constant function $f(x,y)=1$ is a polynomial that seems to satisfy your needs.  I don't understand what you mean by the sentence "Fixing the first input..."

Comment: I suspect he also wants $f(s_i,s_i)\neq 1$.

Comment: @vadim123 yes this is true

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, but I don't know of any clean and simple way to do it.  You need to do a [multivariate interpolation](http://www.siam.org/students/siuro/vol1issue1/S01002.pdf) of the points $$(s_i,s_j,1) (i\neq j)$$ and $$(s_i,s_i,0)$$

These are $n^2$ conditions, so you should expect to get a polynomial with $n^2$ monomial terms, whose coefficients are determined by the process outlined in the above link.  This will be guaranteed to pass through the $n^2$ points, so $f(s_i,s_i)=0$ for each $i$, and $f(s_i,s_j)=1$ for each $i\neq j$.  However, there may be other zeroes of this polynomial, and other places where it assumes the value 1.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, inyour example $1,2,3$ are relativly prime, $(1,2)=(1,3)=(2,3)=1$.

For the first pair {$1,2$} we have that $(-1)\cdot 1+1\cdot 2=1$. For the second pair {$1,3$} we have $(-2)\cdot 1+1\cdot 3=1$. Then the polynomial $f(x)=(-1)\cdot (-2)x+1\cdot 1y$ over the ring $\Bbb Z_3[x,y]$ it's ok for the first two pairs.

In general you can do this for all the pairs and take for $f(x)=ax+by$ over the ring $\Bbb Z_3[x,y]$ where $a$ is the product of all the past $a$'s like $(-1),(-2)$ and $b$ is the product of all the past $b$'s like $1,1$.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more. It's unclear what do you mean by the product of all past b's? Also i can't see where you are using the fact that these pairs just happen to be relative prime? You mean that the function is just the gcd?

Comment: Yes the function is somehow a product of gcd functions,but it is over a finite ring $\Bbb Z_3$. i don't know how to do it in an infinite ring.

Comment: Also by chance we have prime numbers.How can it be generalized with composite numbers? Anyway thanx Mitso ;)

Comment: Haha.nice man. Btw do some test with it to see if it's true. I did it too fast (i have though that it may have a little mistake) and i don't have time to see it again now.i'll see it later when i'll be back from cinema:P